# What happens when two units attack each other with equal support?

Tags: diplomacy

We have the following orders:

England:

- F Nor - Swe.
- A Den S F Nor - Swe.

Russia:

- F Swe - Nor.
- F St. P (NC) S F Swe - Nor.

Both have an equal strength. How does this resolve?

Answer (score 8):

In the rules as of 2015, this is covered under "Standoff Rules":

> Units can’t trade places without the use of a convoy. If two units are each ordered to the province that the other occupies, neither can move.

and then in "Support in Standoffs":

> Diagrams 10 and 11 show two common standoff situations. In both cases, a strength of 2 meets a strength of 2 and all units stand in place. In Diagram 10, if there had been a Fleet in the Tyrrhenian, it wouldn’t be dislodged by the standoff. (A standoff doesn’t dislodge a unit already in the province where the standoff took place.)

Since the two units both have the same support, they cause a standoff and neither one moves.

However, if any other unit was moving into Sweden or Norway with support, then the unit in that province would be dislodged since its support related only to its move order.

Answer (score 2):

Not much to add to ConMan's answer, if there are no other orders affecting the involved units, the result is a stand-off. But bear in mind that if any unit of different nationality moved to Den or StP (i.e. different nationality than the unit currently occupying that space), the support from that space would be cut. Thus, when adjudicating manually, always cut any support orders first, before comparing strength of individual battles.

When in doubt, try using an open source adjudicator such as Realpolitik: http://realpolitik.sourceforge.net/